# How can I change the default wordpress password hashing system to SHA1 with no salt?

Tags: wordpress, hash

I want wordpress to use sha1 hash to save all new user passwords & check it on loging.
I found this custom plugin, but it's not clear as to how I can put SHA1
Make php file in the plugin folder custom_wp_password_override.php

```
             <?php
             /*
             Plugin Name: Custom WordPress Passwords
             Plugin URI: http://localhost
             Description: Override wordpress pluggable password functions.
             Version: 1.0.0
             Author: Your Name
             Author URI: http://locahost
             Text Domain: custom-wp-passwords
             */
            if ( !function_exists('wp_check_password') ) :
            function wp_check_password($password, $hash, $user_id = '') {
           // Your custom code in here
           }
          endif;

         if ( !function_exists('wp_hash_password') ) :
           function wp_hash_password($password) {
           // Your custom code here
         }
         endif;

         ?>
```

I'm supposed to put SHA1 on [ // your custom code here(see above) ]
But I don't know how I can do that please help
thank you

Comment: Did you check this answer here [How can I change the default WordPress password hashing system to something custom?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90373/how-can-i-change-the-default-wordpress-password-hashing-system-to-something-cust)

Comment: Yeah  I checked, it writes //apply your own hashing structure here, which I don't know how I put it

Comment: [Hashing algorithms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) are out of WordPress scope and are already PHP territory. As for functions, they are supposed to return validator or hashed password. You can see who WordPress does it in [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/).

Answer (score 0):

If it's still an issue, just put `sha1($password)` in there